# Making 4 types of question

Tags: questions, auxiliary-verbs, do-support, tag-questions, wh-questions

What the right way to make 4 types of question with "has" in the sentence?

My take on this, though it's really wrong I'm pretty sure:

- She has to get up early.

  - Has she to get up early?
  - Has she to get up early or not?
  - She has to get up early, hasn’t she?
  - When has she to get up?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Exchange! - Is this an exercise that you have been given by a teacher or that you found in a book? If so can you please give the question exactly as it was stated in the original words? Your answers are okay but they aren't what most natives would say.

Comment: Who has to get up early?
When does she have to get up?
What does she have to do?
Does she have to get up early?

Comment: Although they seem logical, in US-style English, those sentences aren't OK. Native speakers *here* would not use them. We are pretty insistent on inserting the helping verb "does" when we invert the word order to make a question. Even when the verb is "has". e.g. "She has to do it" becomes "*Does* she *have* to do it?"

Answer (score 3):

You are right that your examples are wrong.

Interrogatives usually require the modal "do" except in highly stylized or obsolete usages.

> Does she have to get up early?
>
> Does she have to get up early or not?
>
> She has to get up early, doesn't she?
>
> When does she have to get up?